# rxjava2 onErrorResumeNext not called

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have the following code in my app's method, which returns some cached data from db.

```
 return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            String json = cacheDb.cacheDao().loadByKey(key).value;
            return json != null ? gson.fromJson(json, Data.class) : null;
        }).onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {return Observable.just(Collections.emptyList()); });
```

I subscribe to this observable with Schedulers.io() scheduler and observe it on the main thread scheduler. 
The problem is: after publishing this code to production I started receiving crashes in fabric:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.app.android.domain.data.cache.DbCacheEntry.value' on a null object reference
>          at com.app.android.domain.data.repositories.DataRepository.lambda$getFavorites$17(DataRepository.java:60)
>          at com.app.android.domain.data.repositories.DataRepository$$Lambda$1.call(Unknown Source)
>          at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromCallable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromCallable.java:42)
>          at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10838)
>          at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableOnErrorNext.subscribeActual(ObservableOnErrorNext.java:38)
>          at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10838)
>          at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
>          at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
>          at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
>          at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
>          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

This logs are totally understandable except one thing: why onErrorResumeNext is not called in such NullPointerException case? I was trying to reproduce this issue with no success, by throwing a new exception right inside callable, but it is always hit onErrorResumeNext. Why onErrorResumeNext is not called in production? How is this even possible?

Comment: can you post full log? are you sure it is happen in this stream?

Comment: @yosriz, sure, added full log